# Move of a struct variable is a "move" but new space in memory is allocated and addresses of underlying values are different

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to understand Rust's move semantics in the case of a struct that contains fields with types that implement the `Copy` trait. Consider the following struct:

```rust
struct Book {
    author: &'static str,
    title: &'static str,
    year: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let bookA = Book {
        author: "Douglas Hofstadter",
        title: "Gödel, Escher, Bach",
        year: 1979,
    };
    
    let addr_bookA: *const Book = &bookA;
    let bookB = bookA; // Move occurs here
    
    // Getting the memory addresses as raw pointers
    
    let addr_bookB: *const Book = &bookB;
    
    println!("Address of bookA: {:p}", addr_bookA);
    println!("Address of bookB: {:p}", addr_bookB);
}
```

Output:

```
Address of bookA: 0x7fff20b1a0b0
Address of bookB: 0x7fff20b1a0e0
```

Given there is a move and bookB takes up the value that was assigned to bookA, I was expecting a shallow copy of the data when `bookA` is assigned to `bookB`. However, when I check the memory addresses of these two variables, they are different.

Could someone help clarify the following points?

1. Why does a move of a struct still result in different memory addresses for the original and the moved-to variables?
2. Is the data actually copied in this scenario, and if so, why does Rust treat it as a move?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=46d009288cc158d6cd4359cb40760250)

Comment: You sure that was moved and not copied? Also possible you may be looking at an address that's no longer valid. Try with something containing `String` which is not `Copy`. You can also dump out the assembly of the compiled executable. You may also get different behaviour with `--release` when building.

Comment: @tadman `Book` does not implement `Copy`, so no, it could not possibly have been copied.

Comment: Yes correct @tadman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is the data actually copied in this scenario, and if so, why does Rust treat it as a move?

Because the only difference between a move and a copy is that with a copy the original can still be used. *Semantically*, both are memcpy (so byte-copy of the source to the target).

Those copies *may* be optimised away, but that's independent of the semantics.

> Why does a move of a struct still result in different memory addresses for the original and the moved-to variables?

Because LLVM does not optimise away the copy. I will confess that I don't know why, I used to assume LLVM would not see the difference between an SSA version of the same thing but clearly it does and either refuses or can not optimise its stack allocation by removing the copy (just relabelling internally). I've never dived into the reason why that could not happen tho, there might be some metadata which rustc is not setting, or some safety corner case which prevents LLVM from doing it.

Comment: I was going to point out that taking the address of both variables can prevent move elision (the as-if rule being violated otherwise) but even if the addresses aren't taken, LLVM doesn't elide the move. Odd.

Comment: I am wondering if `let x = y` is guaranteed to change address. Probably this is totally unspecified tho

Comment: @cdhowie How do you determine that the move isn't elided when the addresses aren't taken? As far as I can tell using godbolt, the Rust-level "move" doesn't affect the generated assembly - compare [no move](https://godbolt.org/z/oeh8f4WTY) and [move](https://godbolt.org/z/c16froaez).

Comment: @user4815162342 Oh, you are right. For some reason in the "move" version I didn't notice that the line initializing `bookA` has no corresponding generated assembly. So it seems the move is indeed elided if you don't take the addresses.

Comment: @cdhowie I'd certainly hope so. :) If you consider how many such "moves" are generated in all the code we use (think iterators, serde, etc.), it's hard to imagine how zero-cost abstractions would work without at least some amount of move elision.

Comment: @user4815162342 I thought that odd as well. Anyway, I've written my own answer to point out that obtaining the addresses of the variables forces the optimizer not to elide the move.

Answer (score 5):

> Why does a move of a struct still result in different memory addresses for the original and the moved-to variables?

Quite simply, because you observed the addresses.  This forces the optimizer to realize two different locations to hold their data; the very act of obtaining the addresses prevents the optimizer from eliding the move.  (In your case you print them out, but the optimizer likely is unable to figure out that the function you hand them off to to perform the formatting *isn't* going to dereference them.)

As Professor Farnsworth once said:

[image: No fair! You changed the outcome by measuring it]

If you remove the code that obtains and prints the addresses, and then inspect the resulting assembly, you will see that [there is no code generated for the move](https://godbolt.org/z/c16froaez).  (The highlighting here is misleading, because the line `let bookB = bookA` shows generated code, but note that the line initializing `bookA` does not.  If you remove the line with the move, the generated assembly will be identical.  It seems the optimizer is simply delaying initialization until the line with the move, and so it associates the generated assembly with that line instead of with the line initializing `bookA`.)

If you are curious what optimizations are being performed, you should inspect the resulting assembly directly. **Modifying your code in an attempt to determine what optimizations are being performed can change which optimizations are performed.**

Comment: I'm not actually sure the as-if rule applies here. Those two values never exist _at the same time_, so there's no requirement that their addresses be different. It could be a missed optimization opportunity.

Comment: @user4815162342 Possibly, but I think it's a good basis to understand the behavior. I've seen other cases, where e.g. obtaining the address of a variable (even if the address is never dereferenced) causes the optimizer to allocate stack memory for the variable even if it could store the value exclusively in a register. I think the idea is that once you obtain the address, the optimizer can no longer reason about how you're going to use it, so it must assume a different location to be safe.

Comment: *it's a good basis to understand the behavior* - agreed, it's just that the original formulation made it sound like the optimizer is forced by language semantics into the observed behavior. Whether the current behavior is a bug/limitation in rustc or LLVM, or perhaps intended behavior to protect certain usages is a complex question. See [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/61849) for some interesting discussions on the topic.

Comment: @user4815162342 I've since reworded that part of my answer.

Comment: Oh, and by "certain usages" I meant "certain **unsafe** usages". (Search e.g. for "unsafe" in the linked issue.)

Comment: And, to close (from my side, for tonight), there's [this mind-boggling issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/62321). It's a veritable rabbit hole.

Comment: @user4815162342 Fun, I should go paste the Farnsworth image into that thread. ;) (Not really, though.)

Comment: Theoretically, since the addresses escape, they could be used via the raw pointers even after the move. In Rust semantics, [it is undecided whether this is valid](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/188); in LLVM semantics, it is valid. So LLVM cannot optimize the move away. If we decide that in Rust it's UB, we probably want to make it UB for LLVM too somehow.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman *they could be used via the raw pointers even after the move* - thanks, that's a great example of behavior that extant unsafe code might exploit, and that would be disabled by this optimization. It seems pretty far-fetched that real code would make use of it, but you never know.

Answer (score -2):

In Rust, a move operation means transferring ownership of a value from one variable to another. When a struct is moved, the ownership of the data is transferred, but the actual data is not copied. Instead, the original variable is considered no longer valid and cannot be used further.

However, when you create a new variable and move the struct to it, the new variable will have its own memory address, different from the original one. This is because each variable in Rust has its own unique memory address, regardless of how it was initialized.

So, in your case, bookB has a different memory address than bookA, even though it now owns the data that was originally owned by bookA. The data itself was not copied, but bookA is now considered invalid and cannot be used.

This is part of Rust's ownership system, which is designed to prevent issues like double free, null pointer dereferencing, and other common bugs in systems programming. It also helps Rust to manage memory safely without needing a garbage collector.

Comment: It cannot be that "bookB has a different memory address than bookA", but at the same time "The data itself was not copied". Either the address is the same (and the data is not copied), or addresses are different (and the data is copied). More importantly, it's not true that "each variable in Rust has its own unique memory address". The optimizer is perfectly free to reuse the same memory for different variables, store some variables in registers, and eliminate others altogether.